# Delayed execution on shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, iscsi, debian-stretch

I made a simple script file on my linux machine to mount a iscsi drive.

```
iscsiadm –m node --targetname THE_TARGET_IQN --login
mount /dev/sdb1 /home/mounted
```

The problem is, When I exceuted this script, It always fail at first time. Likes this.

```
/etc/init.d# ./iscsi
Loggin to [iface: default, target: targetname, portal: THE_TARGET_IQN (multiple)
Loggin to [iface: default, target: targetname, portal: THE_TARGET_IQN successful.
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
/etc/init.d# ./iscsi
isciadm: default:1 session requested, but 1 already present.
isciadm: Could not log into all portals
/etc/init.d#
```

I think that If I can insert some delay between two lines, It will be fine. Is this reasonable?. Please advise me for this.

Comment: What's the relationship between the first & second lines?

Comment: The first one is engaging a ISCSI And second one is to mount a ISCSI volume

Comment: I don't have `iscsiadm` on my system, but a web man page doesn't appear to have any options to make it wait before returning to the terminal... little weird that it returns immediately before it's finished, but it looks like sleep is your best option, +1 to Deeh

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is delay between two commands, you can add `sleep X`, where X is value in seconds.

```
iscsiadm –m node --targetname THE_TARGET_IQN --login
sleep 3
mount /dev/sdb1 /home/mounted
```

If you need it to mount on boot (it's not clear from your post). Then you need to add /dev/sdb1 to /etc/fstab with `_netdev` option and make sure iSCSI is running on boot.

Comment: Hi. I wanted to mount on boot as you mentioned. Thanks.
So I made a script file to the /etc/init as an startup script. 
If there is better way, Can you share with me?

Comment: Have a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/499246/iscsi-auto-startup-at-boot-14-04